# Synchronizing outputs from PLC and inputs on another device

Tags: plc, twincat

I want to send multiple output signals as a group from the PLC to inputs on a different device. If I just read the inputs from the PLC using the device I often do not get updated signals. Eg. one of the outputs from the PLC may be set HIGH by the PLC, but is read as LOW by the device because of slow communication between the systems.

What are some best practices to ensure I have read all the outputs correctly?

eg. is this a common approach?

### PLC

```
State := 100    <- initial value

--------------------

CASE State OF:
    100: // Init
        ReadFromPLC := FALSE
        I := 1
        OrderRead := FALSE

        State := 200
    200:

        OUT_Value1 := 2 + (I * 2)
        OUT_Value2 := 78 + I
        OUT_Value3 := NOT OUT_Value3

        OUT_readFromPLC := TRUE

        State := 300
    300:
        IF IN_OrderRead AND NOT OrderRead THEN
            OrderRead := TRUE

            OUT_readFromPLC := FALSE
        ELSEIF OrderRead AND NOT IN_OrderRead THEN
            OrderRead := FALSE

            I := I + 1
            State := 200
        END_IF
END_CASE
```

### Receiving device

```
Cycle:

    SIGNAL -OUT_OrderRead
    SWAIT IN_readFromPLC

    read_value1 = BITS (1001, 16)
    read_value2 = BITS (1017, 16)
    read_value3 = SIG (1033)

    SIGNAL OUT_OrderRead

    ...

    GOTO Cycle
```

I have tried multiple google searches, but I can't seem to find anything or are unable to specify the correct search terms.

Comment: Welcome @kjdf! Could you explain some details? What is this "Receiving device"? Another PLC? How you connected it to the PLC?

Comment: Hi, @dwpessoa, I have tried to illustrate the problem better by editing the question. The receiving "device" are the inputs of a robot over Ethernet. On occasions the outputs from the PLC seem to be delayed by the Ethernet communication and are misread by the robot. Eg. the previous value is read by the robot even if the PLC has updated the value.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a network delay, you would need to read the documentation for the robot and in particular about the network protocol, you might be missing something there.

Comment: What Ethernet protocol are you using to communicate with the robot?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that OUT_readFromPLC is set simultaneously with the other OUT values in state 200 and that your Ethernet protocol probably doesn't guarantee which values are transmitted (and arrives) first.

Also, your receiver has no state and keeps reading the values even when OUT_OrderRead is set TRUE and until it receives a IN_readFromPLC=FALSE. The Ethernet communication could still be actively modifying the signals in this period.

One solution is to insert some more states and then keep OUT_readFromPLC=FALSE while modifying the values, make a short delay to make sure the transmission has happened, then set it TRUE.

The receiver should then trigger on a rising value, read the values once, and then not read anything until the next rising value.
This way you can clock the values out from the PLC. And you can keep using the read acknowledge from the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

How about this then?

PLC:

```
DelayOrderReady : TON;
State           : INT := 100;

--------------------

CASE State OF:
    100: // Init
        OrderWritten := FALSE;
        OrderRead := FALSE;
        DelayOrderReady(IN:=FALSE);
        OUT_OrderReady := FALSE;

        State := 200;
    200: // Prepare next order
        // Ensure IN_OrderRead is FALSE before preparing a order
        IF IN_OrderRead THEN
            RETURN;
        END

        // Set output values
        IF NOT OrderWritten THEN
            OUT_Value1 := x;
            OUT_Value2 := y;
            OUT_Value3 := z;

            OrderWritten := TRUE;
        END_IF

        // Wait 1 sec before setting order ready
        DelayOrderReady(IN:=TRUE, PT:=T#1s)
        IF DelayOrderReady.Q THEN
            DelayOrderReady(IN:=FALSE);

            OUT_OrderReady := TRUE;
            OrderWritten := FALSE;

            State := 300;
        END
    300: // Wait for order to complete
        IF IN_OrderRead THEN
            OUT_OrderReady := FALSE;
            OrderRead := TRUE;
        END_IF

        // Wait for order to complete
        IF OrderRead AND IN_OrderDone THEN
            OrderRead := FALSE;
            State := 200;
        END_IF
END_CASE
```

Kawasaki robot:

```
SIGNAL -OUT_OrderRead
SIGNAL -OUT_OrderDone
OrderRead = FALSE
OrderDone = TRUE

State = 100

Cycle:

    CASE State OF
        100:
            CALL SafeHome
            State = 200

        200:
            ; Waiting for order
            IF OrderDone AND SIG (IN_OrderReady) THEN
                Value1 = BITS (1001, 16)
                Value2 = BITS (1017, 16)
                Value3 = SIG (1033)

                PULSE OUT_OrderRead, 1
                SWAIT -IN_OrderReady

                State = 300
            END
        
        300:
            ; Carry out order
            OrderDone = FALSE

            ...

            PULSE OUT_OrderDone, 1

            OrderDone = TRUE
            State = 200
    END

    GOTO Cycle
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).